What does "fac-tronic" mean on "UNIVAC fac-tronic System"?
Researching the UNIVAC I, I found one programming manual that refers to the UNIVAC I as "UNIVAC fac-fronic System", but I did not see any reference as to why "fac-tronic" is there or what it means. I also found a report of some kind that also uses "fac-tronic".
So, does "fac-tronic" have some real meaning? And if so, what does it mean?


The exhibit in the Deutsches Museum München is called "UNIVAC I Factronic", which makes it sound like a model name...

Pure guesswork, but given that the photograph appears to be a drum memory of some sort (or is that the mercury delay line memory?), and the text talks about processing a geodetic database, it may refer to a system that stores "facts" -- i.e., fact-ronic.

@DaveTweed  YouTube says it's mercury delay line storage - which I'd never have guessed.

@dave: Cool! So the system in the brochure must have 10 of those tanks, for a total of 100 delay lines.

More a hint from memory than a full answer.
To my understanding the term Fac-Tronic referred to the claim of UNIVAC I, as well as later II and III, being installed at a Customers Facility in contrast to being operated at the manufacturers or a common use site. Being able to install a computer with the capabilities of the Univac I at any place and any company in the world was a (if not the) major claim of Remington-Rand in 1950. So more of a marketing term than a technical one (rhymes also nicely with Fact).
Also used it as family designation in form of UFT in contrast to UFC (Univac File Computer) and UCT (Univac Calculating Tabulator) (the scientific line was ERA 11xx, although the ERA was dropped later on).

Found a somewhat supporting paragraph at Vipclub(*2), possibly most important Univac/Unisys site there is:

UNISYS is proud to claim that we possess the world's longest unbroken series of computers which started when ERA received government permission to market a commercial version of the then  'classified' Atlas computer.  ERA had shipped the Atlas to the National Security Agency predecessor's cryptography department in October of 1950.  It was fully operational in December 1950 - the world's first stored program computer in a customer's facility.

Not really a proof, but a sign of he mindset those guys had.

*1 - The Brochure can as well be found direct on Archive.Org
*2 - Vipclub is an organisation of 'Retirees and former employees of Unisys, Lockheed Martin, and their heritage companies'

That is interesting, and would make a lot of sense. If I may ask, how do you have a memory from that? Did you work on Unisys or something like that? I am not saying you are lying -- just curious.

@Schilive Have worked in mainframes since the end of the 70s, and quite curious about the stuff ... also was gifted to learn from masters that had worked on the very early systems. This includes learning a lot of that early mindset and being taught in a terminology way different than today. But as mentioned, it's just faint memory I think I know.

Raffzahn, that is really cool. Thanks I would put that in your answer, so the reader understand why you might know that stuff.
